# How to parse a String into Java Tree?

Tags: java

I have a method that generates pop-up menu with many submenus. Basically these menus given dynamically so I have to have algorithm to handle creating submenus using below string.
In order to do it I will need to transform this string into Java Tree by splitting using the delimiter. I am stuck on how to handle splitted string data and translate to the Java Tree Model according to Parent and children nodes.

An Example of Dynamic String Values that I need to parse:

**String str = " Menu1; Menu2; [Menu2A; Menu2B; [Menu2B-A; Menu2B-B];]; Menu3; ";**

**After Handling operation The output should be:**

```
                                 Pop-up Menu
                                 /    |     \
                           Menu1    Menu2   Menu3
                                 /     | 

                              Menu2A     Menu2B
                                          |       \
                                          |        \
                                       Menu2B-A  Menu2B-B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

- Traverse the string from left to right, collecting characters into a current string variable.
- If you encounter a `;` put the current string in a data structure holding `(level, array of menu entries for level)`.
- If you encounter a `[` call recursively with the rest of the string and level + 1.
- If you encounter a `]` return.

Some approximate Java code:

```
private int parseString(String input, String parent, 
                        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> levels) {

     StringBuilder currentString = new StringBuilder();
     int index = 0;
     while(index < input.length()) {
         char c = input.charAt(index);

         if(c == ' ') { // ignore spaces
             index++;
             continue;
         }

         if(c == ';') { // end of menu entry, add to the list
             if(!currentString.toString().isEmpty()) {
                 levels.put(currentString.toString(), new ArrayList<String>());             
                 levels.get(level).add(currentString.toString());
             }
             currentString.delete(0, currentString.length());
             index++;
             continue;
         }

         if(c == ']') { // end of sublist, return
             return index + 1;
         }

         if(c == '[') { // start of sublist, recursive call
             int temp = parseString(input.substring(index + 1), 
                                    levels.get(parent).get(levels.get(parent).size() - 1), levels);
             index += temp;
             index++;
             continue;
         }

         currentString.append(c);
         index++;             
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tudor! I am trying to identify what exactly Parent variable is and what kind of data will it hold? @Tudor

Comment: `parent` is just a string holding the name of the parent.

Comment: well `input` will hold menu item names, `parent` will hold a string but do I need to handle `parent` separetely in order to get the parent from `input` variable?? sorry I am bit confused. @Tudor

Comment: @mbasol: No, this is just an internal use variable. The first time you call the method you have to pass your initial string in the `input` variable, some initial string in parent, like "root" or whatever you want and an empty `Map` as the last parameter, where the output will be stored.

Comment: By the way! I forgot to ask. I am planning to use JPopupmenu with JMenuItems. If I want to load back this Tree model into JPopupmenu accordingly what would be cleaniest way to do because I have to handle level for menu entries. @Tudor

Comment: @mbasol, so you also need the level of each menu entry?

Comment: yes indeed! would be possible to create JPopUpmenu using this Tree without using recursive? @Tudor

Comment: I think you could create it directly from this method. For each item that has children create a new `JMenu` and for each item has not children create a `JMenuItem`.