# How to form a tree with a String

Tags: java, tree

If i have a String as follow

( (a || b) && c) || (d && e)

How can i split them into diffrent string based on the brackets and form a tree like that?

```
         ( (a || b) && c) || (d && e)  ---> Root

               /                \
              /                  \
           ( (a|| b) || c)      (d && e)
           /           \             /  \             
          /             \            /   \
         (a || b)        c           d    e
```

Comment: 'Like that' is not a valid criterium. At the very least you should give a detailed explanation of how the string has to be split. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Twisted trees giving way to lower overhead trees, in what direction do not see the terms of some leaves.

Comment: To process the sort of arbitrarily nested operators and parenthesis you descrive is non-trivial. You'll need a parser.  Not hard to write, but not really something you can want to bang out in a Main()...

Comment: Do you need to worry about the precedence of `||` and `&&`?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368570/how-to-parse-a-string-into-java-tree?

Comment: @ireeder maybe a dup, but we're getting some good information here.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel
I have the following code
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
  Matcher mm = p.matcher(value6);
  while(mm.find()) {
   System.out.println(mm.group(0));
  }

Result
((a || b)
(d && e)

Only manage to split these out

Comment: @TonyEnnis yes, i tot of storing the precedence as a variable if the node has a left and right child

Comment: This is a LOT to figure out on one's own and it's a well-solved problem.  I very much recommend you Google 'operator precedence parser' and 'recursive descent parser'.  The former is a stack-based table-driven parser that has the power to do what you need.

Comment: The hardest part could well be printing the tree, lol.  It will be much more detailed and have many more levels that what you show above.  Parsing is an amazing thing to see happen.  Embrace it!

Comment: Do you have to literally print the tree as shown, or just process the string as shown (using standard conventions...)

Comment: @TonyEnnis

i dont have to print the tree out. I will just like to use it to evaludate the values within according to the brackets.
I am trying think i can parse this notation using the shunting-yard algorithm.
Thats what i am trying out now

Comment: The Shunting Yard wiki says, "The shunting-yard algorithm has been later generalized into operator-precedence parsing."  I'd skip it and go straight to the OPP.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a parse tree generator.   For heavy lifting many use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), but for simple grammars, I've had good success with JavaCC and [JJTree](http://javacc.java.net/doc/jjtreeREADME.html)

Comment: I have never used those. As an aside, how complex does the input language need to be to make learning them and using them worthwhile?

Comment: @TonyEnnis I've only had to write a parser about 3 times in my 15 year career.  In most cases I implemented them directly in my programming language of choice (C++ or Java) but they turned out  brittle.   The last time I invested 4 hours to learn JavaCC, and was happy with the flexibility of the generated parser.  My grammar was only slightly more complicated than the one for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are suggesting probably falls into computer science's branch of **parsers and formal languages**.

A parser program based on an arbitrary grammar for an arbitrary string can be generated with tools like lex & yacc.

Lex is a lexical analyzer program generation tool, which takes as input a text file that defines the lexical rules of your grammar as regexp, and outputs a program capable of recognize tokens from an arbitrary input string as you defined them in the rules.

Yacc is a syntax parser program generation tool, which takes as input a lexer, a text file that represents the grammar of your language (in your case, that would be an expression-like grammar), and outputs a program called **parser** which will be able to transform your expression string into a tree as you mention (i.e. parse the string into a parse-tree).

Yacc and lex can be easily used together to generate a parser program that creates a parse-tree based on so-called **semantic-actions** with which you instruct the parser to build the tree in the way you want.

I suggest you the following as an introductory reading:
http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/

If you are interested in the matter, a more challenging reading would be:
[http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-Edition/dp/0321486811/ref=pd_sim_b_9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)

Yacc and Lex are made only for the C language, equivalent tools exist for the Java.
My favorite parser-generator tool in java would be: http://goldparser.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'll comment about another part of the question,

> ...and form a tree like that.

If you truly mean to print that as output, you'll find it tricky.

As you learn more about parsing, you'll find you'll be manipulating a stack that contains the values of input tokens previously read but not yet processed.  The stack will be implicit if you use a recursive mechanism, or it could be explicit if you use an iterative method and manage the stack yourself.  For a simply operator precedence parser, the latter would be a common implementation.

So, my recommendation is you create a List of `StringBuilder`s.  This is parallel to the stack. That is, `stringBuilderList.get(3)` would be associated with `yourStack.get(3)` etc.

Now when you perform some action such as reducing `( a )` to `a`, you would append a suitable string to the `stringBuilderList` item corresponding to the current stack level.

Now, before you get concerned, another interpretation of your quote is simply that the input be parsed intelligently and in the standard fashion, with items in parentheses being process first, etc.  I recommend you get some clarification to your requirements.