# Interpret User-specified Mathematics

Tags: c++, user-input, interpreter

I have a program which loops through a number of data points, performs an operation on each data point, and returns a result for each data point. Say,

```
for(int i=1;i<LEN-1;++i)
   result[i]=operate(userfunc,i);
```

Internally, I can define several variables which contain the values of various neighbours of the data point.

```
double operate(string userfunc, int i){
    double next=data[i+1];
    double prev=data[i-1];
    double me=data[i];
    userfunc(me,prev,next);
}
```

I imagine the user providing an input string containing the mathematical operation they'd like to perform along with the variables they'd like to work with, such as:

```
0.5+me*min(prev,next)
```

My question then is whether there exists a library which would facilitate parsing the user's input. My current thoughts include using Boost.Spirit or a number of regular expressions. But perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: Maybe not an easier way, but see my answer to a similar question to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043488/how-to-form-a-tree-with-a-string/18043681#18043681

Comment: I'm not sure about the size and scope of your application. Maybe you should think of embedding lua or spidermonkey.